# click on hyperlink (navigateuri) in one view should open another view in WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, hyperlink, wpf-controls

I am working on a `WPF` project which implements the `MVVM` architecture. I have a requirement where, a click on a hyperlink in one view(ux){Usercontrol} should open another view(window). I am able to load a view(usercontrol) through another view(window) by simply mentioning `namespace:UsercontrolViewName` in the host view, but I am clueless about how to do it through a hyperlink.

```
<UserControl x:Class="CCSAdvantage.AddOn.UX.DisplayPhoneNumbersView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:res="clr-namespace:CCSAdvantage.AddOn.UX.Internationalization"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CCSAdvantage.AddOn.UX" 
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"                    
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" mc:Ignorable="d>

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0">
            <HyperlinkNavigateUri="">AdditionalPhone(s)/Manage</Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>         
</UserControl>
```

This is the code for my `UserControl`, the `Grid` has other elements but I eliminated the details for simplicity. `Additional Phone(s)/Manage` => On clicking this link, a new window view which is also in xaml should open up. I tried giving the `Window` views name in the navigateuri property, but it does not work

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some relevant code, and elaborate on the elements you are having issues with?

Comment: I edited the question , hope I expressed my query in a better way this time around, please do not hesitate to ask me for further clarifications. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My problem was accessing the another view(v2) from the current view(v1), I am in. This can be achieved by using a delegate which is called at runtime in the v1's viewmodel, which calls window loader function in V2, this would load the window view(v2)

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Hyperlink in WPF Application](http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2009/03/26/using-hyperlink-in-wpf-application/).

Comment: My problem was accessing the another view(v2) from the current view(v1), I am in. Not navigation to another url. I solved my problem by using a delegate. Thanks!